# python get unicode string size

Tags: python, utf-8, binaryfiles, python-2.x

I have a binary file. This file contains an UTF-8 string. Moreover, it is guaranteed that this string is just a single word.
In python, how can I get number of letters in this string?

Let's say, I opened this file and read bytes:

```
bytes = open("1.dat", "rb").read()
```

What next have I to do to find out length (in letters, not bytes) of UTF-8 string?

Comment: What is the relevance of "it is guaranteed that this string is just a single word"?

Comment: Do not open the file in binary mode.  Open it with `codecs.open` and give it an encoding argument.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
unicode_string = bytes.decode("utf-8")
print len(unicode_string)
```

Comment: In Python 3, you can set `bytes = len(open('1.dat', encoding='utf-8').read())`