# Umlaut counts as an extra letter. How to overrule this in python?

Tags: python

I coded a reading experiment, in which words are presented one by one on a screen.These words are drawn from .txt files (UTF-8), containing German words that are divided into syllables. The division between syllables is done by means of ‘-’. So the .txt file contains words like this:

> zwei-ter Die-ner künst-li-che Würst-chen

The aim of the program is to correctly show the word, so without the ‘-’:

> zweiter Diener künstliche Würstchen

When a word does not contain an Umlaut everything goes fine, using the following code:

```
# Strip newlines and split into syllables
    syllables = word.strip().split( '-' )

    word = ''.join( syllables )

    # Index for keeping track in which color to display the next syllable
    color_index = 0

    letter_count = 0

    for syllable in syllables:

        # Pad the syllable for spaces for every letter of the word that is not part of this syllable
        # This ensures proper placement of the syllable on the screen
        padded_syllable = ' ' * letter_count + syllable + ' ' * ( len( word ) - letter_count - len( syllable ) )

        text = visual.TextStim( 
                win=window, 
                text=padded_syllable, font='Courier New', color=colors[color_index], colorSpace='rgb',
                units='pix', pos=( 0, -234 ),height =68,
        )
        text.draw()

        letter_count += len( syllable ))
```

However, the spacing between word parts goes wrong when a letter contains an umlaut, then this letter seems to be counted as two.
“künst-li-che” is then shown as “künst li che”, where it should be "künstliche".

Is there a way to count a letter with Umlaut as one letter only?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056496/python-get-unicode-string-size

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to strip out all hyphens (and nothing you've said suggests you aren't) then you can just remove them like so:

```
<string>.replace('-','')
```

Example:

```
'zwei-ter Die-ner künst-li-che Würst-chen'.replace('-','')
'zweiter Diener künstliche Würstchen'
```

I also don't get the problem you describe using join

```
>>> y = 'zwei-ter Die-ner künst-li-che Würst-chen'.split('-')
>>> y
['zwei', 'ter Die', 'ner künst', 'li', 'che Würst', 'chen']
>>> ''.join(y)
'zweiter Diener künstliche Würstchen'
```